# ¿Qué significa "dragoneante" en Colombia?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, palabras-raras, colombia

¿Qué significa "dragoneante" en Colombia y por qué? ¿Se usa oficialmente en el sistema penitenciario o se trata de una jerga?

No aparece en el diccionario, pero [dragonear](https://dle.rae.es/dragonear), sí.

Comment: ¿En qué contexto lo has visto usar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dragoneante: Soldado destacado que, luego de seguir un entrenamiento especial, obtiene un mando sobre otros soldados de su misma o inferior antigüedad. Estos soldados son empleados generalmente como comandantes de escuadra.

Forma parte de la escala de rangos de las fuerzas militares de Colombia. Los hay tanto en el ejército como en la policía y también entre los guardianes del sistema penitenciario.

[Fuente: Escalafón militar de Colombia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Escalaf%C3%B3n_militar_de_Colombia_(Ej%C3%A9rcito))

También se usa en Chile según esta [fuente de wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabo_dragoneante) y esta otra fuente de la [Escuela de suboficiales de Chile](https://www.escueladesuboficiales.cl/dragoneante.html) en donde se cita que:
[image: Dragoneante Chile]

Answer (score 2):

> #### [dragoneante.](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=dragoneante)
>
> **I.**
>
> 1. m. *Co*; m-f. *Bo*. Soldado que reemplaza al cabo en ausencia de este.
> 2. m-f. *Ar*. *En las Fuerzas Armadas*, cadete, y antiguamente **conscripto**, que por sus méritos desempeña funciones propias de un rango superior al suyo.
> 3. *Ch*. obsol. Militar que desempañaba una obligación o función sin contar aún con un título para hacerlo.

- DAMER (RAE)